# Any simulator packages for quantum annealing/adiabatic quantum computation?

Tags: programming, simulation, annealing, adiabatic-model

Are there any simulator packages for quantum annealing/adiabatic quantum computation, like Qiskit Aer but for quantum annealing?

There seems to be only classical heuristics in [D-Wave Ocean package](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/stable/), such as simulated annealing and tabu solvers, but nothing that actually simulates the dynamics or results of a quantum annealer.

Comment: Are you looking for Simulated Quantum Annealing? In which case, looks like there is a package: https://github.com/shinmorino/sqaod